# Searching class-intersections of many hierarchies for maximum/minimum values

Tags: algorithm, search, hierarchy

Suppose we have some data for a large number of people (e.g. salary).

Suppose further, that each person is classified in several hierarchical groups.

E.g. they are classified by their location (Toronto < Ontario < Canada), and by their role (Software Engineer < IT).
Anyone who lives in Toronto, also lives in Ontario, and anyone who is a Software engineer is also in IT.

Now, what is the most efficient way to find out what intersection (e.g. Luxembourg, Investment Banker) contains the people with the highest average salary?

([Simpson's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) leads me to believe I need to brute force search, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: In this case brute force search is just constructing a table that maps (smallest location category, smallest job category) to (number of people, total salary) and then finding the pair associated with the largest average salary. This is pretty much linear in the size of the input data, which is about as efficient as you might hope for, whether you call it brute force search or not.

Comment: @mcdowella, Simpson's paradox seems to offer counterexamples to the notion that combining smaller groups leads to intuitive results.

Comment: I am merely suggesting that you consider each smallest size group in turn. Using updates to a hash table - or for that matter an SQL query - you can work out all the averages for all of the smallest size groups in time linear in the input data size.